# how to get length of couch.get(data,headers,status)

Tags: json, node.js, express, npm, couchdb

I tried to create nodejs with expressjs by connecting to couchdb . For that I have used nodejs-couch installed using npm.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  couch
    .get(dbName, viewUrl)
    .then(
      function(data, headers, status) {
        console.log(data.length);
        var data1 = data.data.rows;
        console.log(data1);
        res.send(data1.length);
      },
      function(err) {
        res.send(err);
      }
    );
});
```

my json data :

```
[
  {
    "id": "7a6a4d9cf76efc00977ca63ca3002a31",
    "key": "7a6a4d9cf76efc00977ca63ca3002a31",
    "value": {
      "name": "nagarjuna",
      "email": "nagarjuna@gmail.com",
      "password": "12345",
      "mobile": "987654321",
      "rev": "8-c90103f1fca709ae314a684c767c97dc"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "7a6a4d9cf76efc00977ca63ca3003743",
    "key": "7a6a4d9cf76efc00977ca63ca3003743",
    "value": {
      "name": "sandeep",
      "email": "sandeep@gmail.com",
      "password": "54321",
      "mobile": "9876541",
      "rev": "1-fd6e667b87794adea78e169bc46016e6"
    }
  }
]
```

I had written get function to fetch all customer information. If I print `console.log(data.data.rows);` I am able fetch json data. But I want to get length and attribute values from json. But when I print `console.log(data.length);` it getting `undefined`.

Can any one suggest me. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand you correct, you want to know how many rows you got from the database? try console.log(data.data.rows.length);

Comment: @R.Gulbrandsen thanks man. console.log(data.data.rows.length); worked out. you are greate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result from the database contains a lot of different information, like meta information and the results. Here is a trimmed down representation of what you're looking for

```
var data = {
  data: {
    rows: [{row1},{row2}...];
  }
}
```

So for you to be able to get the length of rows from the database, you'll have to dig into the right attribute in the object like this:

```
var length = data.data.rows.length;
```

Comment: I am trying to fetch attribute value from above mentioned json data. But I am unable to get it.   console.log(data.data.rows.value.email);

Comment: I am trying to do some thing like  if(data.data.rows.value.email=='nagarjuna@gmail.com' && data.data.rows.value.password=='12345'){
    res.send("authenticated");
   }else{
    res.send("unauthenticated");
   }

Comment: Because the rows are a list, you have to specify the element in the list you want to get the email from. like data.data.rows[0].value.email

Comment: you saved my day. Thank you